# Online appointment book

Tags: web-apps, scheduling, hosted, reservation, booking

I need multiple people to be able to log in and enter appointments into my schedule. I'd like to be able to customise the information that is required for an appointment such as 'client name', 'contact number' and 'address', etc. I need to be able to view my schedule on my phone.

It would be good for the future if I could have multiple practitioners on the same schedule, working simultaneously. So to enter an appointment you select the practitioner so that it checks that the practitioner is not busy.

Do you know of an app that will do all of this? I saw a browser-based one but I don't know what it was. Is there a free one?

Comment: Does it have to be free? Does this need to be self-hosted or can it be/has to be an online service?

Comment: An online service is easier for me. Doesn't have to be free, just not to expensive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try HourHQ from Timekit: http://hourhq.com/ You can use a version of their hosted and branded service for free, but you send your users to their site. Plans that you can host are five dollars per user per month.

[Timekit.io](http://timekit.io) looks very cool, but it's $99 a month.

You can find open source stuff for php with MySQL, like http://easyappointments.org/, but you need your own server.

Syncs to Google Calendar so you can check that easily on your phone.

Then there's stuff like [simplybookme](https://simplybook.me/company/prices), free for 50 appointments per month.

Answer (score 0):

**Booked Scheduler.** There are multiple options. The most flexible free / open source software that I know of is [Booked Scheduler](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/free-trial-signup). It definitely supports custom attributes for reservations, and multiple practicioners, called "resources" in the software. You can download the program and host it yourself, of book a 10 USD/month hosting service from the developer.

**More options.** For alternatives that are available as free / open source software, see [my detailed research](https://edgeryders.eu/t/6629). I think I found more or less all of them.